TextView fadeEdge to fade text on the left side
I have a text view to display the digits entered by the user. I want to add fading to the left of the text when the digit entered is long and cannot fit in the textView. I.e I want the least recently entered digit to disappear and faded on the left and the most recently entered digit to show on the right. However, the fade always is on the left side no matter what I do. Note that I am only able to change the xml layout and the fade is only for when that the text cannot fit into the textView horizontally.
Here is the xml code for the text view:
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_title"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:textDirection="ltr"

        android:fadingEdgeLength="90dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:ellipsize="start"/>

Any help?
I tried setting text android:textAlignment to "textStart", "textEnd", "viewStart", "viewStart". I did the same for android:gravity. I also tried setting android:ellipsize to "start", "end", none. None of these achieved what I wanted.
